# Spark Hive reporting ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.biginsights.bigsql.sync.BIEventListener

Tags: apache-spark, hive, ibm-cloud, hadoop-yarn, biginsights

I'm attempting to run a pyspark script on BigInsights on Cloud 4.2 Enterprise that accesses a Hive table.

First I create the hive table:

```
[biadmin@bi4c-xxxxx-mastermanager ~]$ hive
hive> CREATE TABLE pokes (foo INT, bar STRING);
OK
Time taken: 2.147 seconds
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/usr/iop/4.2.0.0/hive/doc/examples/files/kv1.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE pokes;
Loading data to table default.pokes
Table default.pokes stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=0, totalSize=5812, rawDataSize=0]
OK
Time taken: 0.49 seconds
hive>
```

Then I create a simple pyspark script:

```
[biadmin@bi4c-xxxxxx-mastermanager ~]$ cat test_pokes.py
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()

from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hc = HiveContext(sc)

pokesRdd = hc.sql('select * from pokes')
print( pokesRdd.collect() )
```

I attempt to execute with:

```
[biadmin@bi4c-xxxxxx-mastermanager ~]$ spark-submit \
    --master yarn-cluster \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --jars /usr/iop/4.2.0.0/hive/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar, \
           /usr/iop/4.2.0.0/hive/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar, \
           /usr/iop/4.2.0.0/hive/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar \
    --files /usr/iop/4.2.0.0/hive/conf/hive-site.xml \
    test_pokes.py
```

However, I encounter the error:

```
You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_pokes.py", line 8, in <module>
    pokesRdd = hc.sql('select * from pokes')
  File "/disk2/local/usercache/biadmin/appcache/application_1477084339086_0485/container_e09_1477084339086_0485_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 580, in sql
  ...
  File /container_e09_1477084339086_0485_02_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at 
    ...
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at 
    ...
    ... 27 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Failed to instantiate listener named: com.ibm.biginsights.bigsql.sync.BIEventListener, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.biginsights.bigsql.sync.BIEventListener)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getMetaStoreListeners(MetaStoreUtils.java:1478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    ... 32 more
```

See also previous errors related to this issue:

- [hive spark yarn-cluster job fails with: "ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262756/hive-spark-yarn-cluster-job-fails-with-classnotfoundexception-org-datanucleus/41263218#41263218)
- [Spark Hive reporting pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Table not found: XXX' when run on yarn cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263670/spark-hive-reporting-pyspark-sql-utils-analysisexception-utable-not-found-xxx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use hive-site.xml from the spark-client folder:

```
[biadmin@bi4c-xxxxxx-mastermanager ~]$ spark-submit \
    --master yarn-cluster \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --jars /usr/iop/4.2.0.0/hive/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar, \
           /usr/iop/4.2.0.0/hive/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar, \
           /usr/iop/4.2.0.0/hive/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar \
    --files /usr/iop/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml \
test_pokes.py
```

This is captured in the docs: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.2.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.product.doc/doc/bi_spark.html